# Unknown data binding attribute: onLongClick - Attribute exists and works

Tags: android, android-databinding

In my data binding layouts, I set long click listeners via:

```
android:onLongClick="@{ ..binding expression.. }"
```

The code runs as expected, but the `android:onLongClick` attribute is flagged as 'unknown' in the xml file. Additionally, there is no auto-complete for it.

The binding adapter for this attribute is included with the data binding library in `ViewBindingAdapter.java`.

Comment: Maybe we could help you if you shared more info, such as the layout file (at least data nodes) and the handler java file.

Comment: The relevant code is the `onLongClick` attribute. It works as intended, but marked as unknown by AS.

Answer (score 6):

As said [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) you can use: `android:onLongClick="@{() -> handler.onLongClicked()}"`

but if you want to remove warning you can use below code instead of above:

`app:onLongClickListener="@{() -> handler.onLongClicked()}"`

if you use `app:onLongClickListener` data binding will find `setOnLongClickListener` in the `View` class and will use that method

There is a difference between `onLongClickListener` and `onLongClick` : We have a method in view called `setOnLongClickListener` but we do **not** have a method like this: `setOnLongClick` and when you use an attribute `atr` in data binding that has a method like `setAtr` data binding will find and use that method automatically **not needing** any adapter. Thus `onLongClickListener` do **not** need any adapter (if there is an adapter it will be used instead of `setOnLongClickListener`) but `onLongClick` always **needs** adapter.

Comment: `onLongClickListener` and `onLongClick` are both included in `ViewBindingAdapter.java` and perform the same action. Why is one flagged as unknown, while the other is not. Both attributes work. That's really my question, just trying to understand the logic behind that.

Comment: @nearlySane There is a difference between `onLongClickListener` and `onLongClick` : We have a method in view called `setOnLongClickListener` but we do NOT have a method like this: `setOnLongClick` and when you use an attribute `atr` in data binding that has a method like `setAtr` data binding will find and use that method automatically NOT needing any adapter. Thus `onLongClickListener` do NOT need any adapter (if there is an adapter it will be used instead of `setOnLongClickListener`) but `onLongClick` always NEEDS adapter.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Bahman for the helpful answer. Here's some more details and options.

If one uses the native xml binding `app:onLongClickListener` then the viewModel must return Boolean or android compilation crashes with `cannot generate view binders java.lang.StackOverflowError`

So this crashes the compiler: `app:onLongClickListener="@{() -> viewModel.onLongClickRowNoReturn()}"` assuming the viewModel method does not return Boolean. If it returns a boolean it works. The Boolean is required by `View.OnLongClickListener` see [View.OnLongClickListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener)

Alternatively we can use our own custom adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("onLongClick")
fun setOnLongClickListener(view: View, listener: Runnable) {
    view.setOnLongClickListener { listener.run(); true }
}
```

XML: `app:onLongClick="@{() -> viewModel.onLongClickRowNoReturn()}"`

[Here's the docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions) as Bahman also linked, though they are not very informative regarding this issue.

My viewModel example:

```
    override fun onLongClickRow():Boolean {
        Toast.makeText(context, "LongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        return true
    }
    override fun onLongClickRowNoReturn() {
        Toast.makeText(context, "LongClick without return", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`onLongClick` and `onLongClickListener` do the exact same thing because there is a BindingMethod that connects `onLongClick` to `setOnLongClickListener` in `ViewBindingAdapter.java`.

It seems like the IDE just complains about any `android:` prefixed attributes that don't exist in the framework. This is why it doesn't complain about the `app:` versions. However, they are not always freely interchangeable because for example `android:text` does some performance optimizations under the hood whereas `app:text` would just call `setText` directly.